# Differences between two formulations of the Lehmann-Scheffe Theorem

Tags: statistics

I have seen different formulations of the Lehmann Scheffe Theorem but am not sure if they are the same. For example, on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem) it states:

If $T$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$ and $E(g(T)) = \tau(\theta)$, then $g(T)$ is the uniformly minimum-variance unbiased estimator (UMVUE) of $\tau(\theta)$.

But [here](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~hart/611/Lehmann.Scheffe.pdf) it states that:

If $T(X)$ is a complete
sufficient statistic and $W(X)$ is an unbiased
estimator of $τ(θ)$, then $φ(T) = E(W|T)$ is
an UMVUE of $τ(θ)$. Furthermore, $φ(T)$ is the
unique UMVUE in the sense that if $T^*$ is any
other UMVUE, then $P\theta(φ(T) = T^*) = 1$ for all
$θ$.

At a glance, it seems that the first wikipedia statement is needed for the second, and that the second uses the Rao-Blackwell Theorem. Are these two statements one and the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my inference notes I have the second statement as the theorem and the wikipedia statement as a corollary or application.

What's the difference?

Well, they are actually the same, maybe wikipedia statement is a particular case of the other, but there's no loss of generality. You are trying to get the UMVUE, and you know that it is $E[W|T]$ for a $W$ an unbiased estimator and $T$ sufficient and complete. But what Wikipedia says is that if you have the sufficient complete statistic then a second order function $h$ of $T$ will be an UMVUE for $E[h(T)]$ because $E[h(T)|T]=h(T)$. So if you have $h(T)$ unbiased you have directly the UMVUE, what it is more easy to calculate beacause you don't need conditioned distributions.